# Why doesn't a string based template variable change in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I know I can embed a var such as `$aa` in the string k expression, so line 3 displays the result 10.

I think the var k will change when I change the value of aa, so I think the line 5 will display the result 15, but in fact it displays 10. why?

```
1  var aa=10
2  var k="$aa"
3  toast(k)  //This is  10

4  aa=aa+5
5  toast(k)   //This is  10, I think it should be 15

6  k="$aa"
7  toast(k)   //This is  15
```

**Added Content**

I think the system will recalculate line 5 in the following code, so I think the new value aa 15 will be embed into k, but in fact , I get the result "10 bb", why?

```
1 var aa=10
2 var k="$aa"
3 toast(k)    //This is  10

4  aa=aa+5
5  k=k+" bb"   //I think system will recalculate, so I think new value 15 will be embed into k
6  toast(k)   //This is  "10 bb", I think it should be "15 bb"
```

Comment: What's hard to understand in below answer? Strings are immutable. Period. The system itself cannot  detect you updated a value. The string value of 10 is assigned to k, it's not always a templated variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write down this line:

```
var k = "$aa"
```

... the string template on the right side of the assignment is evaluated immediately, and what gets assigned to `k` is the result of the template itself, the literal `"10"` string. That line is the same as if you had and of these in Java - and of course these won't change automatically later as `aa` gets updated either:

```
String k = "" + aa;

String k = String.valueOf(aa);

String k = new StringBuilder().append(aa).toString();
```

To recompute this value every time, you could introduce a local function that you call over and over to create new strings every time, with `aa`'s then current value inserted into the template:

```
var aa = 10
fun k() = "$aa" // same as: fun k(): String { return "$aa" }
println(k()) // 10

aa += 5
println(k()) // 15
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable and the reference `k` points to the specific string "10". That string is made up of the value of the content of your variable `aa`.

If `k` were to change with mutation to `aa` would demand a few things:

- Strings are partially mutable (which has significant speed impacts)
- every templated string would have to be recomputed on nearly every access
- the scope of its creation would have to be closed around (see "closure") so the variables could be kept in reference
- Subsequently, there would be phantom objects on the heap.

That is a lot of computational overhead to display a string.

To connect my two points, the last line of your example evaluates as you expect because your variable now points to a different string "15", because the value that the variable `aa` holds is different than previously at string construction time.

Comment: Thanks! but what you mean is hard to understand.

Comment: Would you please see my added content in my question?

Comment: Immutable strings simply won't be recomputed. I was long-winded in answering.

Comment: If you want a template to be regularly regenerated, evaluate a method or property accessor

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin doesn't have "lazy evaluation", and `var k = "$aa"` is not a function call, it's just an evaluation and instantly assignment. Then when you ask `var k = "$aa"`, `"$aa"` is evaluated, and `k` is assigned.

After that, `k` will "forget" about how it was evaluated, so you do `aa = aa + 5` will have no effect on `k`.

For the "Added Content", regarding the same thought of above, `k` has been "forgot" how it was evaluated, assigning `k = k + " bb"` will just directly add the *existing* `k` (program level joining, not memory level concatenate) with string " bb", not re-evaluate `k` with "$aa".